# SwiftUi value into a let statement

Tags: dynamic, binding, swiftui

I want to make this let dynamic to what is passed into the item property.

if I change the 'forResource' to a static name everything works.  I just can't make it dynamic.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct PdfDetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: String

   let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: $item, withExtension: "pdf")!

    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Pdf view")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("PDF Below)
                        .font(.title)
                }
                PDFKitView(url: documentURL)


            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in `init`:

```
struct PdfDetailView: View {
    let documentURL: URL

    init(item: String) {
        documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: item, withExtension: "pdf")!
        // you could handle errors here as well (instead of force unwrapping optionals)
    }
    ...
}
```

And in some other View call it like:

```
PdfDetailView(item: "someItem")
```

In this other view your item property may be dynamic (eg. `@State`) but it doesn't have to be dynamic in the `PdfDetailView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution (of course assuming you make sure the URL is valid before creating `PdfDetailView`)

```
struct PdfDetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Pdf view")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text("PDF Below")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            PDFKitView(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: item, withExtension: "pdf")!)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is possible alternate if item string is not guaranteed to be valid

```
struct PdfDetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: String

    var body: some View {
        let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: item, withExtension: "pdf")
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Pdf view")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text("PDF Below")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            if documentURL != nil {
                PDFKitView(url: documentURL!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```